# Generating a unique key

Tags: python, python-3.x, strings, random

I am coming from a Ruby background and I am learning Python. This is a method I've created to generate a URL safe unique key:

```
import random;

def generate_unique_key():
    array = []
    for letter in range(97,123):
        array.append(chr(letter))
    for letter in range(65,91):
        array.append(chr(letter))
    for number in range(0,10):
        array.append(number)
    for char in ["-", ".", "_", "~"]:
        array.append(char)

    random_values = random.sample(array, 15)
    random_values = map(lambda x: str(x), random_values)
    return "".join(random_values)

print(generate_unique_key())
```

Coming from a Ruby background I was certainly puzzled first at not being able call `join` directly on my list, but having to call it from a string instance.

Also in Ruby I would have written something similar to `random.sample(array, 15).join("")` directly without having to convert them all to string, but this I believe this is how `join()` works.

While this works, how can this function be more Pythonic?

Comment: @Peilonrayz Apologies, this is indeed python 3. I was testing on a python 2.7 interpreter which is why the print looks like that, but I will be using it in a python 3.7 environment

Comment: It generates a _random_ key, but why would you say that it's _unique_? What are you using it for?

Comment: http://lucumr.pocoo.org/2011/7/9/python-and-pola/ Not the best English, but a good read nonetheless than I think will help clear things up for you.

Comment: @200_success: Alright, I posted an answer based on my earlier comment. Originally thought that my criticism was a little out of scope for CR but upon further consideration I came to a different conclusion. Thanks for the reminder!

Answer (score 15, accepted):

1. You can pass `str` to `map` rather than a `lambda`.
2. You can remove the need for `map` if you change your third loop to append `str(number)`.
3. You can use [`string`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/string.html) to remove the need for `chr` and `int` in the first three loops. By using:

   1. [`string.ascii_letters`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/string.html#string.ascii_letters):
      abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyzABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZ
   2. [`string.digits`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/string.html#string.digits):
      0123456789
4. You can combine all your loops into one string concatenation.
5. Don't use `;` to end lines.
6. You can define `array` as a constant outside the function.
7. I recommend using Python 3, or changing `print` to be Python 3 compatible.

```
import random
import string

CHARACTERS = (
    string.ascii_letters
    + string.digits
    + '-._~'
)

def generate_unique_key():
    return ''.join(random.sample(CHARACTERS, 15))

print(generate_unique_key())
```

---

You can also use the [`secrets`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/secrets.html#module-secrets) library (thanks @[MathiasEttinger](https://codereview.stackexchange.com/users/84718/mathias-ettinger)) which is a CSRNG version of `random`. It also contains the function [`secrets.token_urlsafe`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/secrets.html#secrets.token_urlsafe) (thanks @[Graipher](https://codereview.stackexchange.com/users/98493/graipher)) which generates a random string which is safe for use in URLs. Allowing:

```
def generate_unique_key(size=15):
    return secrets.token_urlsafe(size)[:size]
```

Comment: 8. Use [`secrets`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/secrets.html#module-secrets).

Comment: @MathiasEttinger And specifically, [`secrets.token_urlsafe`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/secrets.html#secrets.token_urlsafe).

Comment: `I recommend using Python 3, or changing print to be Python 3 compatible.` I consider this bad advice. `print(1, 2)` has a very different meaning in python 2 and python 3. If you're going to give this advice - consider adding the future import to your example.

Comment: @Shadow I'm unsure what part of that is bad advice. You can use future, or migrate away from the should be dead version.

Comment: If you want to make the `print` Python 3 compatible, you should use `from __future__ import print_function`.

Comment: @jpmc26 The way `print` is being used is Python 3 compatible. Yes if you need additional features from the Python 3 print function then you'll have to use future as I highlighted in my above comment.

Comment: @Peilonrayz The problem is that someone might add arguments later, which may not behave as they expect. It's better to just actually use the `print` function.

Answer (score 9):

### Sampling method

[<s>`sample()`</s>](https://docs.python.org/3/library/random.html#random.sample) is the wrong kind of sampling here since it draws *k* random samples from the given population/alphabet *without repetition*. Instead you should should use [`choices()`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/random.html#random.choices) which allows repetition of the same items.

Normally you want as much entropy as possible in the given “space” (here: *k* = 15 items chosen from *N* = 66 Arabic digits, basic Latin letters and some punctuation). If you disallow repetitions you reduce the size of the key space (although not significantly<sup>1</sup>) and risk more (frequent) collisions at no benefit and more costly sample computation<sup>2</sup>.

### Source of (pseudo-)randomness

You should also consider that the `random` module’s default (pseudo-)random number generator is not normally “safe”. See [Gaipher’s comment](/questions/200355/how-can-my-generate-unique-key-method-be-more-pythonic#comment385764_200356) for a possible safe alternative.

### Avoid magic numbers, allow parameters if possible

Additionally you should avoid unexplained "magic numbers" (like 15) and allow parameters (with sensible defaults) for arbitrarily chosen values (like `length`).

### Resulting code

```
def generate_unique_key(length=15):
    array = # ... construct character set
    return "".join(random.choices(array, k=length))
```

For Python versions prior to 3.6 you can provide a simple implementations of `choices()` yourself:

```
import random
try:
    random_choices = random.choices
except AttributeError:
    import itertools
    def random_choices(population, *, k=1):
        return map(random.choice, itertools.repeat(population, k))
```

---

<sup>1</sup> Key space comparison:

- *with* repetition: \$N^k = 66^{15} \approx 2.0 \cdot 10^{27}\$
- *without* repetition: \$\prod^{N}_{i=N-k+1} i = \frac{!N}{!(N - k)} = \frac{!66}{!(66 - 15)} \approx 3.5 \cdot 10^{26}\$

<sup>2</sup> An optimal algorithm for random samples *without* repetition is more complex than one *with* repetition and requires either \$O(k)\$ intermediate storage or \$O(k^2)\$ runtime (with *k* being the sample size) to keep track of previously drawn items.

Answer (score 3):

most pythonic way to generate a URL safe unique key or token is to use [secrets module](https://pynative.com/python-secrets-module/).

Use `secrets.token_urlsafe` it will return a secure random URL-safe text string. The secrets module uses synchronization methods to ensure that no two processes can obtain the same data at the same time.

```
import secrets
print(secrets.token_urlsafe(32))
```

output:

```
GzWfp5xCcuFsnEUb9qqN_v94_XOx9hPwSGszdx4rNBk
```

you can change the byte size as per your requirement